# Differences in Scipy and MATLAB griddata

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have two files with the same purpose, one in Python and one in MATLAB. After reading in a data file, I want them to calculate and error, use `detrend` to remove a constant offset, then interpolate a surface to fit the errors using `griddata`.
However, there seem to be differences in the MATLAB version of `detrend` and `scipy.signal.detrend`, as well as differences between MATLAB's `griddata` versus `scipy.interpolate.griddata`, that I don't quite understand.

The MATLAB code I am using looks as follows:

```
err = posEncUm - posLasUm;

err(:,1) = detrend(err(:,1),'constant');
err(:,2) = detrend(err(:,2),'constant');

[X,Y] = meshgrid(posEncUm(:,1),posEncUm(:,2));

errX = griddata(posEncUm(:,1),posEncUm(:,2),err(:,1),X,Y);
errY = griddata(posEncUm(:,1),posEncUm(:,2),err(:,2),X,Y);
```

Meanwhile, the Python code I am using is:

```
err = posEncUm - posLasUm;

err[:,0] = scipy.signal.detrend(err[:,0])
err[:,1] = scipy.signal.detrend(err[:,1])

mn = np.min(posEncUm, axis = 0)
mx = np.max(posEncUm, axis = 0)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(posEncUm[:,0],posEncUm[:,1]) # makes uniform grid

errX = griddata(posEncUm[:,0],posEncUm[:,1],err[:,0],X,Y,interp='linear')
errY = griddata(posEncUm[:,0],posEncUm[:,1],err[:,1],X,Y,interp='linear')
```

When plotting the data, I get two very different things, and I'm not sure which of these is causing the difference.

This is what the [MATLAB code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB9UZ.png) produces, and this is what the [Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLt0H.png) produces.

I'll post my full code below for both the MATLAB and Python.
Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong?

Full MATLAB code:

```
function ES15302_squareness(myDir)

close all;
cd(myDir);

s = load('outdata.dat');

posEncUm = [s(:,1) s(:,3)]/25000;
posLasUm = [-s(:,2) s(:,4)]/25000;

err = posEncUm - posLasUm;

err(:,1) = detrend(err(:,1),'constant');
err(:,2) = detrend(err(:,2),'constant');

[X,Y] = meshgrid(posEncUm(:,1),posEncUm(:,2));

errX = griddata(posEncUm(:,1),posEncUm(:,2),err(:,1),X,Y);
errY = griddata(posEncUm(:,1),posEncUm(:,2),err(:,2),X,Y);

figure();

subplot(4,2,1);
plot(0.001*posEncUm(:,1),err(:,1),'.');
p = polyfit(0.001*posEncUm(:,1),err(:,1),1);
title(sprintf('Slope = %4.1f um / 100 mm',p(1)*100));
xlabel('Encoder Position (X), mm');
ylabel('Laser Error (X), um');
grid on;

subplot(4,2,2);
plot(0.001*posEncUm(:,2),err(:,1),'.');
p = polyfit(0.001*posEncUm(:,2),err(:,1),1);
title(sprintf('Slope = %4.1f um / 100 mm',p(1)*100));
xlabel('Encoder Position (Y), mm');
ylabel('Laser Error (X), um');
grid on;

subplot(4,2,3);
plot(0.001*posEncUm(:,1),err(:,2),'.');
p = polyfit(0.001*posEncUm(:,1),err(:,2),1);
title(sprintf('Slope = %4.1f um / 100 mm',p(1)*100));
xlabel('Encoder Position (X), mm');
ylabel('Laser Error (Y), um');
grid on;

subplot(4,2,4);
plot(0.001*posEncUm(:,2),err(:,2),'.');
p = polyfit(0.001*posEncUm(:,2),err(:,2),1);
title(sprintf('Slope = %4.1f um / 100 mm',p(1)*100));
xlabel('Encoder Position (Y), mm');
ylabel('Laser Error (Y), um');
grid on;

subplot(2,1,2);
quiver(0.001*X,0.001*Y,errX,errY,5);
axis square
grid on;
xlabel('Encoder Pos (X), mm');
ylabel('Encoder Pos (Y), mm');

% plot the figures
if isempty(strfind(myDir,'\')),
    plotID = myDir;
else
    index = max(strfind(myDir,'\'))+1;
    plotID = myDir(index:end);
end

set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0.5 0.5 7.5 10]);
stampitproprietary(plotID);
eval(sprintf('print -dpdf squareness_%s.pdf',plotID));
cd ..
return;

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------

h = findobj('Type','figure');
cur_fig = get(0,'CurrentFigure');
warning off
for i = 1:length(h)
    set(0,'CurrentFigure',h(i));
    cur_ax = get(h(i),'CurrentAxes'); % gets current axis handle for given figure

    hidn_axis=axes('Position',[0 0 1 1], 'Visible','off','Units','normalized','Tag','Stampit');
    dh(i,1) = text(.905,0.01,plotID);
    set(dh(i,1),'FontSize',[12],'HorizontalAlignment','Right');

    set(h(i),'CurrentAxes',cur_ax); % Sets current axis back to its previous state

    chld = get(h(i),'Children');                              % These lines place the hidden "Stampit" axis
    if length(chld)>1                                         % to the bottom of the figure's Children handle list
        set(h(i),'Children',[chld(2:length(chld)); chld(1)])  % This alieveates problems with zoom and other functions
    end                                           
end

set(0,'CurrentFigure',cur_fig);
pause(.001)
warning on

return;
```

Full Python code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.linalg
from scipy import signal
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.plotly as py
import os
from pylab import *
import math as m
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
#import time
#import calendar
import pylab as pl
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.0, 10.5)

#timestamp = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=5)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=5)
plt.rc('grid', ls='dotted')
plt.rcParams['lines.dotted_pattern'] = [0.1,0.5]

def main(argv):
    testdir = argv[0]
    fname = os.path.join(testdir,'OUTDATA.DAT')

    s = np.loadtxt(fname)    #If in current directory
    s2 = np.transpose([s[:,0],s[:,2]])      # these are 
    s3 = np.transpose([-s[:,1],s[:,3]])     # all going
    posEncUm = np.divide(s2,25000)          # to be
    posLasUm = np.divide(s3,25000)          # 169x2
    err = posEncUm - posLasUm;

    err[:,0] = scipy.signal.detrend(err[:,0])
    err[:,1] = scipy.signal.detrend(err[:,1])

    mn = np.min(posEncUm, axis = 0)
    mx = np.max(posEncUm, axis = 0)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(posEncUm[:,0], posEncUm[:,1]) # makes uniform grid

    errX = griddata(posEncUm[:,0],posEncUm[:,1],err[:,0],X,Y,interp='linear')
    errY = griddata(posEncUm[:,0],posEncUm[:,1],err[:,1],X,Y,interp='linear')

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #plot3 = pl.figure(figsize=(3,4))
    fig = pl.figure(figsize=(3,4))

    gs = pl.GridSpec(3, 2)

    gs.update(left=0.08, right=0.925,
              top=0.95, bottom=0.05,
              hspace=0.6, wspace=0.8)

    plt.subplot(321)
    ax0 = pl.subplot(gs[0, 0])
    plt.scatter(0.001*posEncUm[:,0],err[:,0], s=0.4, linewidths=0.7)
    p = np.polyfit(0.001*posEncUm[:,0],err[:,0],1)
    plt.title('Slope = {0:4.1f} um/100mm'.format(p[0]*100), fontsize=5)
    plt.xlabel('Encoder Position (X), mm', fontsize=5)
    plt.ylabel('Laser Error (X), um', fontsize=5)
    #plt.xlim([-200,200])
    plt.ylim([-30,10])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(-200,201,100))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-30,11, 10))
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(322)
    ax1 = pl.subplot(gs[0, 1]) 
    plt.scatter(0.001*posEncUm[:,1],err[:,0], s=0.4, linewidths=0.7)
    p = np.polyfit(0.001*posEncUm[:,1],err[:,0],1)
    plt.title('Slope = {0:4.1f} um/100mm'.format(p[0]*100), fontsize=5)
    plt.xlabel('Encoder Position (Y), mm', fontsize=5)
    plt.ylabel('Laser Error (X), um', fontsize=5)
    #plt.xlim([-200,200])
    plt.ylim([-30,10])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(-200,201,100))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-30,11, 10))
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(323)
    ax2 = pl.subplot(gs[1, 0]) 
    plt.scatter(0.001*posEncUm[:,0],err[:,1], s=0.4, linewidths=0.7)
    p = np.polyfit(0.001*posEncUm[:,0],err[:,1],1)
    plt.title('Slope = {0:4.1f} um/100mm'.format(p[0]*100), fontsize=5)
    plt.xlabel('Encoder Position (X), mm', fontsize=5)
    plt.ylabel('Laser Error (Y), um', fontsize=5)
    #plt.xlim([-200,200])
    plt.ylim([-30,10])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(-200,201,100))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-30,11, 10))
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(324)
    ax3 = pl.subplot(gs[1, 1])
    plt.scatter(0.001*posEncUm[:,1],err[:,1], s=0.4, linewidths=0.7)
    p = np.polyfit(0.001*posEncUm[:,1],err[:,1],1)
    plt.title('Slope = {0:4.1f} um/100mm'.format(p[0]*100), fontsize=5)
    plt.xlabel('Encoder Position (Y), mm', fontsize=5)
    plt.ylabel('Laser Error (Y), um', fontsize=5)
    #plt.xlim([-200,200])
    plt.ylim([-30,10])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(-200,201,100))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-30,11, 10))
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(325)
    ax4 = pl.subplot(gs[2, :])
    plt.quiver(0.001*X,0.001*Y,errX,errY)
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel('Encoder Pos (X), mm', fontsize=5)
    plt.ylabel('Encoder Pos (Y), mm', fontsize=5)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(-200,201,100))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-200,201,50))
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable = 'box')


    timestamp = os.path.basename(testdir)
    fig.text(0.96,0.01, timestamp, horizontalalignment = 'right',size='small')
    fig.savefig(os.path.join(testdir,"squareness_{0}.png".format(timestamp)))
    fig.savefig(os.path.join(testdir,"squareness_{0}.pdf".format(timestamp)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Did you try with a small file and check the results?

Comment: Small file meaning that I should eliminate some of the data? I could try that, I just wouldn't have a reference, since I have been using the MATLAB code to compare.